# What are most common natural causes of death?

Tags: pathology, death

What are most frequently occurring natural causes of death?

Comment: Without defining 'natural death' this question is opinion-based. I vote to close until clarified.

Comment: @Christiaan moreover, I see no point or purpose behind this question. This is not strictly in the realm of the biology that we consider here. This is more of a census report.

Comment: @WYSIWYG, agreed, and perhaps even more a definition question than anything else.

Comment: Beside the other comments, this also differes between countries, which makes the question a bit unclear and also very broad. And I assume you are talking about **human** causes of death?

Comment: If you survive everything else, you will die of cancer, specific to your own genetics (as the more "popular" types of cancer will be treatable, given some time for research).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WHO has data from 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_causes_of_death_by_rate#cite_note-2) where they have classified and counted causes of death. I have treated the following as *natural* causes:

- Cardiovascular disease (29.34%)
- Infectious & Parasitic disease (23.04%)
- Cancers (12.49%)
- Respiratory disease (6.49%)
- [Perinatal conditions](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Perinatal+Infection) (4.32%)
- Digestive disease (3.45%)
- Neuropsychiatric disorders (1.95%)
- Diabetes (1.73%)
- [Genitourinary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitourinary_system) disease (1.49%)
- Maternal conditions (<1%)
- Congenital abnormalities (<1%)
- Nutritional deficiencies (<1%)
- Endocrine disorders (<1%)
- Neoplasms (<1%)
- Musculoskeletal disease (<1%)
- Skin disease (<1%)

I treated the following as [non-natural causes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_by_natural_causes):

- Intentional injuries
- Non-intentional injuries

The sum of the groups explains 96.7% of deaths. I think the remaining 3.3% would be other or undetermined causes, and rounding errors in the data. The natural causes accounted for 87.9%, and non-natural causes were 9.1%. **The most common causes were cardiovascular diseases, infectious/parasitic diseases, and cancers.**

It is difficult to assess how *natural* the cause of deaths are. For example, many cancers, cardiovascular, and respiratory diseases are more common in obese people and smokers (often self-inflicted damage), nutritional deficiencies are often caused by failing welfare and social systems.

Additionally, among the recorded [causes of death in England and Wales in 2011](http://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2012/nov/06/deaths-mortality-rates-cause-death-2011), of the total 484,367 deaths recorded, 17,590* deaths were from extrinsic sources (accidents, homicides etc.). This is around 3.6% of deaths. **In this data, the most common causes were cancers (29.6%), circulatory diseases 28.8%, and respiratory diseases (14.0%).**

[According to the CDC](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/what-does-it-mean-to-die-of-natural-causes/), in 2013 there were 2,596,993 deaths in the US, and 92.5% were of natural causes. Of those, the principle causes were heart disease (24%) and cancer (23%). There's a good [table at the bottom of this site.](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/what-does-it-mean-to-die-of-natural-causes/)

Rates of natural and non-natural causes of death will likely vary greatly by country given different health risks (e.g. malaria in Africa vs Europe), health care services, extrinsic risks (e.g. traffic accidents in Sweden vs India).

$*$ *The table in the article features a potential mistake, it seems the columns are incorrectly labelled*

Comment: I wonder if suicide due to depression should be considered natural.

Comment: I'd say depression is a natural disease, the whole division in to natural and non-natural causes is weird, too difficult to determine in many cases.

Comment: What is a natural death? All the lung *cancers* due to smoking? *Cardiovascular disease* due to overweight? The question, imo, is primarily *what the definition of a 'natural' death is*, more so than what the various examples are from a medical or pathological standpoint.

Comment: The question is, *among deaths by natural causes, what are the most common?* There is a general consensus, at least, as to what constitutes natural causes.

Comment: And which is...?